# Couldn't able to show the response for wrong credential

Tags: android, retrofit

Iam using Retrofit for logging into the application and did it successfully(Like I can successfully log into device,response is ok) but couldn't able to show Toast or Alert dialog for wrong credentials.Like if any one give wrong password or username I want to show the response from API that "Password or username not correct".I'have tried almost everything but every time get the message "Timeout".Also Toast is working fine eveyrwhere else in that activity but couldn't able to apply it to get the response for wrong credentials.

Here is my Login Activity Code :

```
package com.vshine.neuron.riseshine.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.vshine.neuron.riseshine.R;
import com.vshine.neuron.riseshine.util.SessionManager;
import com.vshine.neuron.riseshine.webservice.ApiClient;
import com.vshine.neuron.riseshine.webservice.ApiInterface;
import com.vshine.neuron.riseshine.webservice.apimodel.login.LoginResponse;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button login_button;
    ImageButton GetRegistered;
    EditText userName_edt, password_edt;
    String user_name, password;
    SessionManager sessionManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        sessionManager = new SessionManager(LoginActivity.this);
        if (sessionManager.isLoggedIn()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            this.finish();

        } else {
            initBasic();
            initLogin();
        }


    }

    private void initBasic() {
        login_button = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        GetRegistered = findViewById(R.id.register);
        userName_edt = findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        password_edt = findViewById(R.id.password);

    }

    private void initLogin() {
        GetRegistered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisteredActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                user_name = userName_edt.getText().toString();
                password = password_edt.getText().toString();
                if (validateLogin(user_name, password)) {
                    //do login
                    doLogin(user_name, password);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean validateLogin(String user_name, String password) {
        if (user_name == null || user_name.trim().length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Username is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        if (password == null || password.trim().length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void doLogin(final String username, final String password) {

        ApiInterface apiService =
                ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<LoginResponse> call = apiService.Login(username, password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {

                LoginResponse loginresponse = response.body();
                if (!loginresponse.getStatus()) {
              /*     AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).create();
                   alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                   alertDialog.setMessage("message");
                   alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                   dialog.dismiss();
                               }
                           });
                   alertDialog.show();*/
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response.code() + "response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    String id = loginresponse.getResponse().getId();
                    String userName = loginresponse.getResponse().getUsername();
                    String firstName = loginresponse.getResponse().getFirstName();
                    String lastName = loginresponse.getResponse().getLastName();
                    String email = loginresponse.getResponse().getEmail();
                    sessionManager.createLoginSession(id, userName, email, firstName, lastName);

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e("", t.toString());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here is the code for ApiClient :

```
package com.vshine.neuron.riseshine.webservice;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://........../vshine/API/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;

    }
}
```

Code for ApiInteface is :

```
package com.vshine.neuron.riseshine.webservice;


import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.vshine.neuron.riseshine.webservice.apimodel.login.LoginResponse;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface ApiInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api.php?action=Login")
    Call<LoginResponse> Login(@Field("user_name") String username, @Field("password") String password);

}
```

Logcat image is :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your login server returns a 401 Unauthorized when there are invalid credentials, you need to check the status code in onResponse.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                if (response.code() == 401) {
                    // show error toast
                    return;
                }
                LoginResponse loginresponse = response.body();
                if (!loginresponse.getStatus()) {
```

Furthermore if you need the response body, since a 401 is an unsuccessful response, you will get the body in `response.errorBody()` instead of `response.body()`. See https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html